# Branching process - finding the extinction probability

Tags: probability, solution-verification, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

> Let $X$ be a branching process with $X_0=1$ and the offspring distribution $V$ is given by $$\mathbb{P}(V=0)=p,\ \ \mathbb{P}(V=1)=2p,\ \ \mathbb{P}(V=2)=1-3p$$ and $0\le p\le\frac{1}{3}$. Let $\eta$ denote the probability the process will eventually become extinct. I want to answer the following questions:
> (a) What is $\mathbb{E}[X_n]$, the expected size of the $n^{th}$ generation?
> (b) Determine the range of values of $p$ for which ultimate extinction is not certain
> (c) For which range of values of $p$ is $\eta<0.1$?

My solutions:

(a) The PGF of the process is $G_V(z)=p+2pz+(1-3p)z^2$. Note that $\mathbb{E}[V]=G_V'(1)=2-4p$. Also, $\mathbb{E}[X_n]=(\mathbb{E}[V])^n=(2-4p)^n$, since $X_0=1$.

(b) Extinction is not certain if $\mathbb{E}[V]\le 1$. Using part (a) this means $2-4p\le 1$,so $p\ge\frac{1}{4}$. But in the question we have $p\in[0,\frac{1}{3}]$. So $\frac{1}{4}\le p\le\frac{1}{3}$ is the range of values of $p$ such that extinction is not certain.

(c) The extinction probability is the least nonnegative root of $\eta=G_V(\eta)$, so in our case we have the equation $$(1-3p)\eta^2+(2p-1)\eta+p=0$$

This means that $(\eta -1)((1-3p)\eta -p)=0$, so either $\eta=1$ or $\eta=\frac{p}{1-3p}$. Solving $\eta<0.1$in this case gives $\frac{p}{1-3p}<0.1\Rightarrow p<0.1-0.3p$, that is $1.3p<0.1$, so $p<\frac{10}{13}$. The reason why I'm confused is that in the question we have $p\in[0,\frac{1}{3}]$, so the bound we just obtained seems a bit useless - it indicates for any $p$ in our range we have $\eta<0.1$. Can anyone advise on this?

Answer (score 1):

You have missed one small point. The roots are $1$ and $\frac p {1-3p}$ (if $0 \leq p <\frac  1 3$). But if $p \geq \frac 1  4$ then the second root is $\geq 1$ and so the extinction probabilty is $1$ (because there is only one root in $[0,1]$). If $p <\frac 1  4$ then what you have done is correct and $p <\frac {10} {13}$ does not put any further restriction.

Answer (score 1):

I would have thought eventual extinction was more likely if $p$ is higher and your "either $\eta=1$ or $\eta=\frac{p}{1-3p}$" seems to confirm this

So eventual extinction is almost certain if $p\ge \frac14$ suggesting the answer to (b) could be $0 \le p \lt \frac14$

You may also have an error in (c), since $0\le 1.3p < 0.1$ implies $0 \le p<\frac{0.1}{1.3}=\frac{1}{13}$